# QGraphicsItem setPos is not moving item's position

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem

What I have is similar to the following:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  MainWindow appWindow;
  appWindow.show();
  return app.exec();
}
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
  ...
private:
  QGraphicsScene *mScene;
  QGraphicsView *mView;
  QGraphicsItem *mItem;
  QPushButton *mButton1, *mButton2;
};
MainWindow::MainWindow(...) {
  mScene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
  mScene->setItemIndexMethod(QGraphicsScene::NoIndex);
  mView = new QGraphicsView(mScene, this);
  mView->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
  mButton1 = new QPushButton("Create Item", this);
  QObject::connect(mButton1, SIGNAL(clicked()), ...);
  mButton2 = new QPushButton("Set Item Position");
  QObject::connect(mButton2, SIGNAL(clicked()), ...);
}
void MainWindow::button1Clicked() {
  mItem = new QGraphicsSimpleTextItem("Test Item");
  mItem->setPos(mItem->pos() + QPointF(7.0f, 7.0f));  // doesn't work
  mScene->addItem(mItem);

  // even when I move the setPos() call after QGraphicsScene::addItem,
  // the item still paints at the top-left corner (0.0f, 0.0f)
}
void MainWindow::button2Clicked() {
  mItem->setPos(mItem->pos() + QPointF(7.0f, 7.0f)); // works perfect
}
```

I'm very very new to Qt and most likely misunderstanding a basic concept. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [`QGraphicsView`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qgraphicsview.html) doc:

> The visualized area is by default detected automatically when the view
>   is displayed for the first time (by calling
>   QGraphicsScene::itemsBoundingRect()).

That means when the view is first shown, it uses the combined item bounds as its bounds. So when you first added the item, whatever the item's position is, it will be used as the top-left of the displayed scene. So your item is actually moved, but the scene is shown with an offset. So it looks like it's at (0, 0). And when you move it the second time, it's actually moved twice already.

The solution is to set the [`seceneRect`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qgraphicsview.html#sceneRect-prop) to a known rect before showing it. That will fix the displayed area.

Comment: I just figured out the solution but before I could post answer to my own question, you did. And yeah you are right, setSceneRect() must be issued for item positioning to work correctly. One more thing I've found out is that as far as positioning is concerned, it doesnt even matter what values I pass to setSceneRect i.e. I tried with 1px for width as well as for height and item was positioned exactly where I wanted. Thanks a lot for explaining it in detail though.